# import/export task markers in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, export, task, markers

Is there any way to import/export task markers in eclipse ?

I know I can copy tasks and paste it in excel [but cant import ], but are there any other ways ?

Comment: I found this link http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm but are there any plugins that use these apis and persist to file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try a different approach to task sharing. Sharing the code over a [**VCS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) ensures that all task markers inside the code like `//TODO` `//FIXME` and such are shared as well.

In order to enhance the visibility of the tasks for all members of your project, you could use [a **Continuous Integration Server**](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with the [**tasks plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Task+Scanner+Plugin). It lets you see the tasks as a graph and track changes. You can also drill down inside the CI server to see the code the task refers to.

Another , more coarse-grained approach would be to use an external [**bug tracker**](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/). Most of them provide [**Mylyn**](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) integration, so you can sync your tasks across the project

Answer (score 1):

Markers (tasks, problems, bookmarks all are markers) are associated and persisted with resources. You cannot export the markers alone. What is your usecase?

Comment: I need to export tasks [code review tasks ] and share them with peers so that they can import them and fix code

Comment: You should be using Mylyn for that.